# Laravel 5.5 Migrations: cannot create foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

So I have three Tables. Clients / Sites / Users. A Client Has Many Sites. A Client Has Many Users. A User / Site belongs to a Client. Pretty straight forward. Sadly we are importing the information for the Site / Client tables from someone who thought it would be a good idea to use string keys.

Here are my migrations -

This is the clients table:

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id', 25)->primary();
    $table->char('number', 6)->unique();
    $table->string('name', 50)->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is the sites table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id', 25)->primary();
        $table->string('name', 30)->unique();
        $table->string('number', 10)->unique();
        $table->string('address_1', 60);
        $table->string('address_2', 60)->nullable();
        $table->string('city', 30);
        $table->string('state', 3);
        $table->string('postal_code', 10);
        $table->string('country', 30);
        $table->string('weather_code')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('dimension', 18, 0)->nullable();
        $table->string('dimension_uom', 10)->nullable();
        $table->string('client_id', 25);
        $table->softDeletes();            
        $table->timestamps();

        // Belongs To Client
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
    });
}
```

This is the users table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('client_id', 25);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        // Belongs To Client
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
    });
}
```

However when I run these I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_client_id_foreign` foreign key (`client_id`) references `clients` (`id`))
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

If I remove the foreign key attempt on users but keep the one in sites it works fine. I am doing exactly the same thing in both yet for some reason it works in sites and not in users. Any idea why?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is when you run migration `user` table get created first and can not find `client` table therfore it sqwaks. So make sure you have `clients` migration running before `users`. Change timestamps.

1. Client migration first
2. User migration after

Comment: That was it. Wow, I feel pretty stupid. Were in the beginning of the app's development so i figured id go modify the original migration instead of creating a new migration.....didn't think about the order. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: glad it helped :) ...make sure to accept the answer tho @BillGarrison